# how to convert from english language tamil with phonetic characters?

Tags: php

**Example.php**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');

require_once 'gtranslate.php';

$gt=new gtranslate();

echo $gt->translate('Hello, I am Don', 'ta','en',true);
```

**gtranslate.php**

```
<?php

class gtranslate {

    function __construct() {
        $this->translate_url = 'https://translate.google.com/m?ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&hl=en&';
        $this->urlReferer = 'https://translate.google.com/m';
        $this->userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
    }

    public function translate($text, $to, $from = '',$cache=false) {
        $url = $this->translate_url . 'sl=' . $from . '&tl=' . $to . '&q=' . urlencode(@$text);

        if(file_exists('cache/'.$to.'/'.md5($url).'.cache') && $cache){
            return file_get_contents('cache/'.$to.'/'.md5($url).'.cache');
        }

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->userAgent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $this->urlReferer);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $resp = $this->parseResponse(curl_exec($ch));
        if(!file_exists('cache')){
            @mkdir('cache');
        }
        if(!file_exists('cache/'.$to)){
            @mkdir('cache/'.$to);
        }
        @file_put_contents('cache/'.$to.'/'.md5($url).'.cache', $resp);
        return $resp;
    }

    private function parseResponse($str = '') {
        $result = strip_tags($str, '<div>');
        $result = explode('<', substr($result, strpos($result, 'class="t0"') + 11, strpos($result, 'class="t0"')));
        $result = $result[0];
        return $result;
    }

}
```

This code translated english to tamil  but what i want is to echo the pronunciation of the word in tamil language .

Comment: How do you want to show something you should hear instead of read?

Comment: I need the pronunciation of english in tamil letters.

Comment: if i type this  "Naan" .....it should return "நான்" in tamil .... not the meaning

Comment: I think he means pronunciation as PHONETICS. Not like the actual voice.

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is *[transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_(linguistics))*. You want to *transcribe* English text into Tamil *orthography*. At which point, I'm pretty sure this becomes a "does anyone know a tool for this?" question rather than a programming one, which is off topic according to the [help].

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for transliteration. https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started here is the api for it.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Google Transliterate API
      google.load("elements", "1", {
            packages: "transliteration"
          });

      function onLoad() {
        var options = {
            sourceLanguage:
                google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
            destinationLanguage:
                [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
            shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
            transliterationEnabled: true
        };

        // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
        // options.
        var control =
            new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

        // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
        // 'transliterateTextarea'.
        control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateTextarea']);
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Type in Hindi (Press Ctrl+g to toggle between English and Hindi)<br>
    <textarea id="transliterateTextarea" style="width:600px;height:200px"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://google-developers.appspot.com/transliterate/v1/richedittransliteration is the real example for it.